# How to install an application locally?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is it possible to install an application locally?

For example, if I create a custom application how can I make it available to my colleagues at work without having to upload my application to an app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is marked as ‘Microsoft Teams’ I will answer it as such:
Custom apps in MS Teams are **not** published to the App Store.  Apps in MS Teams (as generally understood) are not generally freestanding apps either, like win32 apps.

Custom MS Teams Apps are published and authorized via the [MS Teams Admin center](https://admin.teams.microsoft.com).  ***EDIT: this is your O365 Tenant’s Teams Admin Center - always.  Microsoft has no centralized location for evaluating custom apps, unlike the Windows App Store.***  Also, there is no stand-alone app like you describe (and as I interpret your question).  Although you could integrate the API calls needed to interact with MS Teams into a freestanding app, the tightest integration between the MS Teams service and custom apps - i.e.: the quickest path to awesome - is described below.

Apps for teams are developed using the [SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) (spfx).  All the apps are surfaced from within the MS Teams desktop or mobile app (after approval of the custom app in the [MS Teams Admin center](https://admin.teams.microsoft.com)).

The SharePoint framework is built on [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org), which is a type-safe, syntactical superset of Javascript.

Modern SharePoint web parts, application extensions, list & library command sets, etc. are all built upon the SharePoint Framework.

Most importantly, you can use other TypeScript-based framework(s) / libraries within your projects, e.g.: React, Angular, Handlebars, Vue - and even plain-old vanilla JavaScript.  This allows you to leverage any existing familiarity with these frameworks’ conventions.

Teams spfx info links:

- [Build for Microsoft Teams using SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/build-for-teams-overview)
- [Adding a Microsoft Teams tab in SharePoint as an spfx web part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tabs-in-sharepoint)
- [sp-dev-fx-webparts](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts) spfx GitHub Repo
- [sp-dev-training-spfx-teams-dev](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-training-spfx-teams-dev) spfx Teams GitHub Repo

***Please up-vote if this answer helped you!***

Comment: Thanks, Fritz.  So if I want to share an app with my colleagues I will need to locate the people who manage the teams admin centre and request their permission which is probably a non-starter.

Comment: @Chris Snow:  Not necessarily.  Part of the development pipeline for testing apps in spfx is what’s called the SharePoint Workbench.  After setting up all the tooling and developing your alpha & beta projects, the way you test them is via the ‘Workbench’.  The recommended tooling by MSFT, provides a localhost based workbench and in SP Online, you can access the online workbench by navigating to https://YourTenantName.sharepoint.com/_layouts/workbench.aspx .  You can modify which location you are testing in the ‘gulp serve’ command in the project’s /config/serve.json file. (Continued Below)

Comment: @Chris Snow:  (Continued from above)... by using the workbench to both debug UI and functional logic, when you have a polished product, you can then focus on the business case for your projects use.  Remember:  the entire open source pipeline of tools you will be using - if only following the spfx dev samples - is completely owned by Microsoft:  Visual Studio Code, GitHub, and NPM - Microsoft has the entire pipeline locked - but that’s not to say that if you use some obscure NPM build that you are not putting yourself at risk for a supply chain attack.  Hope this helps.  Reach out if more Q’s.